# clearElement DOM not working (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a to-do-list. I think I've created the **CSS** design and done all the **HTML** markup correctly. However, when I'm trying to use `clearElement()` to remove my HTML markup of the `taskContainer` to allow the user input their own task (blank value as default). But my code does not seem to work.

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ruda:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>To-do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="title">To-Do List</h1>

    <div class="all-tasks">
      <h2 class="task-list-title">Task list</h2>
      <ul class="task-list" data-lists>
        <li class="list-name active-list">Work</li>
        <li class="list-name">Study</li>
        <li class="list-name">Youtube</li>
      </ul>

      <form class="center-newlistname" action="" data-new-list-form>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="new-list"
          data-new-list-input
          placeholder="New list name"
          aria-label="New list name"
        />
        <button class="btn-create" aria-label="create new list">Add</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="todo-list" data-list-display-container>
      <div class="todo-header">
        <h2 class="list-title" data-list-title>Daily Task</h2>
        <p class="task-count" data-list-count>3 task remaining</p>
      </div>

      <div class="todo-body">
        <div class="tasks" data-tasks></div>
        <div class="task">
          <input type="checkbox" id="task-1" />
          <label for="task-1">
            <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
            Task 1
          </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Task 1  -->

        <div class="task">
          <input type="checkbox" id="task-2" />
          <label for="task-2">
            <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
            Task 2
          </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Task 2  -->

        <div class="task">
          <input type="checkbox" id="task-3" />
          <label for="task-3">
            <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
            Task 3
          </label>
        </div>
        <!-- Task 3  -->

        <div class="new-task-creator">
          <form action="" data-new-task-form>
            <input
              type="text"
              data-new-task-input
              class="new-list"
              placeholder="New task"
              aria-label="New task"
            />
            <button class="btn-task" aria-label="create new task">+</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="task-delete">
          <button class="btn delete">Clear task</button>
          <button class="btn delete" data-delete-list-btn>Delete list</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <template id="task-template">
      <div class="task">
        <input type="checkbox" id="task-3" />
        <label for="task-3">
          <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
const listsContainer = document.querySelector('[data-lists]')
const newListForm = document.querySelector('[data-new-list-form]')
const newListInput = document.querySelector('[data-new-list-input]')
const deleteListButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete-list-btn]')
const listDisplayContainer = document.querySelector('[data-list-display-container]')
const listTitlElement = document.querySelector('[data-list-title]')
const listCountElement = document.querySelector('[data-list-count]')
const taskContainer = document.querySelector('[data-tasks]')
const taskTemplate = document.getElementById('task-template')
const newTaskForm = document.querySelector('[data-new-task-form]')
const newTaskInput = document.querySelector('[data-new-task-input]')


const LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY = 'task.list'
const LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY = 'task.selectedListID'
let lists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY))||[]
let selectedListId = localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY)

listsContainer.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li'){
        selectedListId = e.target.dataset.listId
        saveAndRender()
    }
})



newListForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const listName = newListInput.value
    if (listName == null || listName === '') return
    const list = createList(listName)
    newListInput.value = null
    lists.push(list)
    saveAndRender()
})
newTaskForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const taskName = newTaskInput.value
    if (taskName == null || taskName === '') return
    const task = createTask(taskName)
    newTaskInput.value = null
    const selectedList = lists.find(list => list.id === selectedListId)
    selectedList.task.push(task)
    saveAndRender()
})

deleteListButton.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    lists = lists.filter(list => list.id !== selectedListId)
    selectedListId = null
    saveAndRender()
})

function createList(name){
  return {id: Date.now().toString(), name: name, tasks: []}
}

function createTask(name){
  return {id: Date.now().toString(), name: name, complete: false}
}

function saveAndRender(){
    save()
    render()
}
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_LIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(lists))
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_SELECTED_LIST_ID_KEY, selectedListId)
}

function render(){
    clearElement(listsContainer)
    renderLists()


    const selectedList = lists.find(list => list.id === selectedListId)

    if(selectedListId == null){
       listDisplayContainer.style.display = 'none' 
    } else {
        listDisplayContainer.style.display = ''
        listTitlElement.innerText = selectedList.name
        renderTaskCount(selectedList)
        clearElement(taskContainer)
        renderTasks(selectedList)
        
    }
}

function renderTasks(selectedList){
    selectedList.tasks.forEach(task =>{
        const taskElement = document.importNode(taskTemplate.content, true)
        const checkbox = taskElement.querySelector('input')
        checkbox.id = task.id
        checkbox.checked = task.complete
        const label = taskElement.querySelector('label')
        label.htmlFor = task.id
        label.append(task.name)
        taskContainer.appendChild(taskElement)
    })
}

function renderTaskCount(selectedList){
    const incompleteTaskCount = selectedList.tasks.filter(task => !task.complete).length
    const taskString = incompleteTaskCount === 1 ? "task" : "tasks"
    listCountElement.innerText = `${incompleteTaskCount} ${taskString} remaining`
}

function renderLists(){
    lists.forEach(list =>{
        const listElement = document.createElement('li')
        listElement.dataset.listId = list.id
        listElement.classList.add("list-name")
        listElement.innerText = list.name
        if (list.id === selectedListId){ 
            listElement.classList.add('active-list')
        }
        listsContainer.appendChild(listElement)

    })
}

function clearElement(element){
    while (element.firstChild){
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild)
    }
    
}

render()
```

What I had expected to happen is: the tasks on the right side should disappear (*Task 1*, *Task 2*, *Task 3*) and allow the user to input their own tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the the `clearElement()` with anything, e.g. `browser.clearElement()`.
Hope this solves it completely.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It was an error in my html, I hadn't closed my div tag for my data-tasks correctly. It should be closed at the end of all the tasks that I had listed in html

**Before**

```
<div class="todo-body">
    <div class="tasks" data-tasks></div>
    <div class="task">
      <input type="checkbox" id="task-1" />
      <label for="task-1">
        <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
        Task 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Task 1  -->

    <div class="task">
      <input type="checkbox" id="task-2" />
      <label for="task-2">
        <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
        Task 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Task 2  -->

    <div class="task">
      <input type="checkbox" id="task-3" />
      <label for="task-3">
        <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
        Task 3
      </label>
    </div>
    <!-- Task 3  -->

    <div class="new-task-creator">
      <form action="" data-new-task-form>
        <input
          type="text"
          data-new-task-input
          class="new-list"
          placeholder="New task"
          aria-label="New task"
        />
        <button class="btn-task" aria-label="create new task">+</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="task-delete">
      <button class="btn delete">Clear task</button>
      <button class="btn delete" data-delete-list-btn>Delete list</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**After**

```
<div class="todo-body">
        <div class="tasks" data-tasks>
          <div class="task">
            <input type="checkbox" id="task-1" />
            <label for="task-1">
              <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
              Task 1
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- Task 1  -->

          <div class="task">
            <input type="checkbox" id="task-2" />
            <label for="task-2">
              <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
              Task 2
            </label>
          </div>
          <!-- Task 2  -->

          <div class="task">
            <input type="checkbox" id="task-3" />
            <label for="task-3">
              <span class="custom-checkbox"></span>
              Task 3
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Task 3  -->

        <div class="new-task-creator">
          <form action="" data-new-task-form>
            <input
              type="text"
              data-new-task-input
              class="new-list"
              placeholder="New task"
              aria-label="New task"
            />
            <button class="btn-task" aria-label="create new task">+</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="task-delete">
          <button class="btn delete">Clear task</button>
          <button class="btn delete" data-delete-list-btn>Delete list</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```